# Dictionary with list of strings as value

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary where my value is a List.
When I add keys, if the key exists I want to add another string to the value (List)?
If the key doesn't exist then I create a new entry with a new list with a value, if the key exists then I jsut add a value to the List value
ex.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
myDic.Add(newKey, add to existing list<strings> and not create new one)
```

Answer (score 50):

To do this manually, you'd need something like:

```
List<string> existing;
if (!myDic.TryGetValue(key, out existing)) {
    existing = new List<string>();
    myDic[key] = existing;
}
// At this point we know that "existing" refers to the relevant list in the 
// dictionary, one way or another.
existing.Add(extraValue);
```

However, in many cases LINQ can make this trivial using `ToLookup`. For example, consider a `List<Person>` which you want to transform into a dictionary of "surname" to "first names for that surname". You could use:

```
var namesBySurname = people.ToLookup(person => person.Surname,
                                     person => person.FirstName);
```

Comment: If you're doing this in a loop, the results will be far from expected. I'd go with a `if the key doesn't exist, add it with an empty list as value. Else fill that value with the requested string.` It makes more sense and is easier to write.

Comment: @KappaG3: I don't know what you mean... particularly around "fill that value" - I believe my answer does what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I didn't read your code carefully and tought it did something quite different.

Comment: noob here: anyone know what would be the explicit type declaration of namesBySurname - the var keyword muddies up the waters for me :'(?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: You can always hover over `var` to see the exact type. In this case it would be `ILookup<string, string>`.

Comment: Take care that this `dict.GetValueOrDefault(key, new List<string>())` **isn't working**!! If you add to the returned list it **doesn't get added to the dictionary** list.

Comment: @Kalaschni: That call *does* work - it just doesn't do what you expect apparently expect it to. If the key isn't found, a new list would be created *but not added to the dictionary*. It's not really clear to me why you've left a comment on this answer which doesn't mention `GetValueOrDefault`, mind you...

Answer (score 21):

I'd wrap the dictionary in another class:

```
public class MyListDictionary
{

    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> internalDictionary = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();

    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        if (this.internalDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            List<string> list = this.internalDictionary[key];
            if (list.Contains(value) == false)
            {
                list.Add(value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.Add(value);
            this.internalDictionary.Add(key, list);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any indication that the "value list" is meant to only contain unique values.

Comment: I cannot think of any good reason to store duplicate strings in a list, except maybe performance...but that's debatable.

Comment: There are *lots* of cases where that would be appropriate. Imagine a case in a shopping system where it was grouping "line items by order ID" - you'd want to tell the difference between "this order was one burger" and "this order was five burgers". In particular, you have silently added behaviour which wasn't in *any* way mentioned in the question, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a dictionary Extension for this:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void AddOrUpdate(this Dictionary<string, List<string>> targetDictionary, string key, string entry)
    {
        if (!targetDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            targetDictionary.Add(key, new List<string>());

        targetDictionary[key].Add(entry);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply add or update:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DictionaryExtensions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var newDic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        newDic.AddOrUpdate("Alpha","Anton");
        newDic.AddOrUpdate("Alpha","Boris");
        newDic.AddOrUpdate("Beta","Doris");
        newDic.AddOrUpdate("Delta","Emil");
        newDic.AddOrUpdate("Alpha","Ceasar");
        
        System.Console.Write(newDic["Alpha"][1].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method receives different params than what you're sending

Answer (score 6):

A simpler way of doing it is:

```
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(it => it.Key).ToDictionary(dict => dict.Key, dict => dict.Select(item => item.value).ToList());
```

Answer (score 5):

Just create a new array in your dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
myDic.Add(newKey, new List<string>(existingList));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is generic extension that can be used for any type.

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(this Dictionary<string, List<T>> targetDictionary, string key, T entry)
    {
        if (!targetDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            targetDictionary.Add(key, new List<T>());

        targetDictionary[key].Add(entry);
    }
    
    public static void AddRangeOrUpdate<T>(this Dictionary<string, List<T>> targetDictionary, string key, IEnumerable<T> entry)
    {
        if (!targetDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            targetDictionary.Add(key, new List<T>());

        targetDictionary[key].AddRange(entry);
    }
}
```

Make sure to use `using System.Collections.Generic;`

Now you can simply add or update using one entry or many entries:

```
using Object = UnityEngine.Object;
...
Dictionary<string, List<Object>> res = new Dictionary<string, List<Object>>();
res.AddOrUpdate("somekey", new Object());
res.AddRangeOrUpdate("somekey", new List<Object> { new Object{} });
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested about performance, the [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault) API is your friend. This API is available from .NET 6 onwards, and allows to perform an `Add` operation with a single hashing of the `key`:

```
public static void Add<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> source,
    TKey key, TValue value) where TKey : notnull
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ref List<TValue> listRef = ref CollectionsMarshal
        .GetValueRefOrAddDefault(source, key, out _);
    listRef ??= new List<TValue>();
    listRef.Add(value);
}
```