# Create csv from a list without duplicating certain columns

Tags: c#, csv

I have a collection `(List<ProfileDo>)` which has the following structure...

```
ProfileDo
- StartDateTime
- EndDateTime
- Volume
```

I am trying to create a csv file which looks like,

```
"StartDateTime", "EndDateTime", "Volume"
```

I am struggling to find a way to stop duplicating "StartDateTime", "EndDateTime" being added to the csv each Profile and just use it once and use the volume from others. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might sounds wired but it could work,

You can create a `Dictionary` like `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` . And combine `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` to a string like `StartDateTime_EndDateTime`. Now when you add Volumes you combine relevent `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` and compare for existence using `ContainsKey()`.

If key exists we add `Volume` to relevant List, else we create a new entry and add.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887407/dictionary-with-list-of-strings-as-value) example might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need is similar to a 2 level control break what we used to call writing cobol programs. Ensure the list is sorted by StartDateTime and EndDateTime. Then when you loop you need to store the current StartDateTime and EndDateTime when it is not the same. Something like this:

```
DateTime? currentStartDatetime = null;
DateTime? currentStartDatetime = null;
string line;  // can use string builder for performance..

foreach (var profile in profiles)
{
  line = string.Empty;

  if (currentStartDateTime != profile.StartDateTime)
  {
     currentStartDateTime = profile.StartDateTime;
     line += profile.StartDateTime + ",";
  }
  else
  {
     line += ",";
  }

  if (currentEndDateTime != profile.EndDateTime)
  {
     currentEndDateTime = profile.EndDateTime;
     line += profile.EndDateTime + ",";
  }
  else
  {
     line += ",";
  }

  line += profile.Volume;

  Csv.WriteLine(line);
}
```