# Cannot wrap my head around using a Dictionary with imbedded list such as dictionary<string, list<string>>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

trying to add a list object to the dictionary however, I cannot grasp the concept being that you have they key, so you cannot do .add without there being a key violation

working on a shopping list program, I need to add inventory to the customer's cart, remove it from the inventory, then add that to the dictionary.

```
    public static Inventory AddToCart(List<Inventory> Inventory)
    {
        // this method moves a dvd from inventory to the shopping cart.
        int i = 0;
        int iInput = 0;
        Inventory newCart = null;
        if (Inventory.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (Inventory obj in Inventory)
            {
                ++i;
                Console.WriteLine("[" + i + "] " + obj.ToString());
            }
            iInput = Validation.GetInt("Please Choose an item to add to cart: ");
            Console.Write($"Move item at record: #{iInput - 1} to shopping cart: (y or n)");
            string sInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sInput))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\r\nNo Valid number was chosen: ");
            }
            else
                switch (sInput.ToLower())
                {
                    case "y":
                        {
                            newCart = Inventory[iInput - 1];
                            Inventory.RemoveAt(iInput - 1);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "n":
                    case null:
                    case "":
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\r\nNo Valid number was chosen: ");
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Keeping item in Inventory");
                        }
                        break;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nNo records were found in the Shopping Cart");
        }
        return newCart;
    }
```

This is using only a list, however I need to be able to convert this over to a dictionary with this list imbedded

Comment: What about something as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17887699/5209435). You could just use the logic in a helper method if you didn't want to create a new class.

Comment: You've listed things that you want, but you haven't asked a question. What's your question?

Comment: I would really want to help you but there is no real question here.

Comment: There's also no dictionary.

Comment: I can't wrap my head either, because you have named an argument `Inventory`, representing a list of `Inventory` objects. It is very confusing. A better name for the argument would be `inventoryList`. Give meaningful names to your variables, and much of the confusion will go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question but here is some explanation on how to work with dictionaries that contain lists in  general.

You have dictionary that consists of a key and a List.

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dictionaryWithList = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

If you want to save something into this List you have to create a key-value pair first. This means adding an element to the dictionary containing the key and the list. If you want to have your list filled while adding the key value pair you could do something like this:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add(5);
myList.Add(6);
myList.Add(7);
dictionaryWithList.Add("test", myList);
```

Now you have a list containing 5, 6 and 7 that you can access with the key "test" inside of the dictionary.

If you want to access the list you just use:

```
dictionaryWithList["test"]
```

So if you want to add a new number to the list that has the key "test" then you can use:

```
dictionaryWithList["test"].Add(42)
```

If you want to avoid running into Exceptions caused by keys not existing, test if a key exists first:

```
if(dictionaryWithList.ContainsKey("test"))
```

Notify me if this hasn't helped you with some further information about your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    string newKey = "NEW KEY";
    string firstListElement = "FIRST";
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    if (dict.ContainsKey(newKey)) { 
        // you need to throw an exception or return some signal to exit function
    }
    dict.Add(newKey, new List<string>());
    dict[newKey].Add(firstListElement);
```